# Internal mesh communication is ignoring settings from the virtual service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to inject an HTTP status 500 fault in the bookinfo example.

I managed to inject a 500 error status when the traffic is coming from the Gateway with:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
  namespace: default
spec:
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - fault:
       abort:
          httpStatus: 500
          percent: 100
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Example:

```
$ curl $(minikube ip):30890/api/v1/products
fault filter abort
```

But, I fails to achieve this for traffic that is coming from other pods:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
  namespace: default
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  hosts:
  - productpage
  http:
  - fault:
       abort:
          httpStatus: 500
          percent: 100
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Example:

```
# jump into a random pod
$ kubectl exec -ti details-v1-dasa231 -- bash

root@details $ curl productpage:9080/api/v1/products
[{"descriptionHtml": ... <- actual product list, I expect a http 500
```

- I tried using the FQDN for the host `productpage.svc.default.cluster.local` but I get the same behavior.
- I checked the proxy status with `istioctl proxy-status` everything is synced.
- I tested if the istio-proxy is injected into the pods, it is:

Pods:

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
details-v1-6764bbc7f7-bm9zq      2/2     Running   0          4h
productpage-v1-54b8b9f55-72hfb   2/2     Running   0          4h
ratings-v1-7bc85949-cfpj2        2/2     Running   0          4h
reviews-v1-fdbf674bb-5sk5x       2/2     Running   0          4h
reviews-v2-5bdc5877d6-cb86k      2/2     Running   0          4h
reviews-v3-dd846cc78-lzb5t       2/2     Running   0          4h
```

I'm completely stuck and not sure what to check next. I feel like I am missing something very obvious.

I would really appreciate any help on this topic.

Comment: you configure external and it works but have you configure something for internal communication? any networking policy? if yes could you provide it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and does when I tried. My guess is that you have other conflicting route rules for the productpage service defined.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of my issues were an improperly set up includeIPRanges in my minicloud cluster. I set up the 10.0.0.1/24 CIDR, but some services were listening on 10.35.x.x.